# Wrong blending in OpenGL on small alpha value

Tags: opengl, pixel, blend, alphablending, blending

I draw from texture a lot of white traingles. But when it are drawing on yellow circle, the points which contains a small alpha value(but not equal with 0) are blended wrong, and I get some darker pixels on screen(see on screenshot, it was zoomed in). Which can be the problem?
On blue background all are ok.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like an interpolation issue between a white pixel with a low alpha-value and an black pixel which has an alpha-value of 0 (the outside of the arrow which is completely transparent).

Comment: It can be a problem of video driver?

Comment: No, its just how interpolation works. Not sure __how__ an image-editing program saves completely transparent pixels but if I'm right it just saves them as black as it (normally) doesn't matter. Thats bad though. You should preprocess your image before you upload it and set all pixels which have an alpha value of 0 to white.

Comment: Big RESPECT to you. I render the image in my program (from SVG). It will be a application for smartphones and it will support high DPI. I just changed the clear color for image before drawing from svg. It works!

Comment: If I set the Magnification Filter and Minification Filter  to Nearest helps too.

Comment: Yeah, this disables interpolation. If that's not a problem for you (sharp edges) then this works aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tklausi pointed out in the comments, this problem was related to the texture interpolation in combination with traditional alpha blending. At the transition from values with high alpha to "background" with alpha=0, you will get some interpolation results where alpha is > 0, and RGB is mixed with your "background" color.

@tlkausi's solution was to change the RGB values of the background to white. But this will result in the same issue as before: If your actual image has dark colors, you will see bright artifacts around it then.

The correct solution would be to repeat the RGB color of the actual border pixels, so that the interpolation will always result in the same color, just with a lower alpha value.

However, there is a much better solution: **premultiplied alpha**.
Instead of storing (R,G,B,a) in the texture per pixel, you store (aR,aG,aB,a). When blending, you don't use `a*source + (1-a) * background`, but just `source + (1-a)*background`. The difference is that you now have a "neutral element" (0,0,0,0) and interpolation towards that will not pose any issue. It works nicely with filtering, and is also good for mipmapping and other techniques.

In general, I would recommend to *always* use premultiplied alpha in favor of the "traditional" one. The premultiplication can be directly applied into the image file, or you can do it at texture upload, but it does incur no runtime costs at all.

More information about premultiplied alpha can be found [in this MSDN blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/shawnhar/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha/) or [over here at NVIDIA](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/alpha-blending-pre-or-not-pre).